# Issues with .htaccess and URL routing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I have written this .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_\#]+)\.?([a-zA-Z]+)?$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2&extension=$3 [QSA,L]
```

What I expect to achieve with this is, when a request like this: mydomain.com/en/account/settings.html, where 'en' is the current working language, 'account' the controller, etc; it should be separated and redirected in this form: index.php?lang=en&url=account/settings&extension=html, this is working perfectly.
But when the request looks just like this mydomain.com/en without the last trailing slash, it fails and makes the controller name look like this: NController, by picking the last 'n' in 'en' for language and adding it to the url when the url is supposed to be without value. Now what I want is for url to remain empty when the uri ends in 'en' with or without the last trailing slash, if no controller is requested.

With such uri `http://localhost/application/en/`,
This is what I get `Array ( [lang] => en [url] => / [extension] => )`

But with this: `http://localhost/application/en`
I get this instead: `Array ( [lang] => e [url] => n [extension] => )`

But what I simply want is `Array ( [lang] => en [url] => [extension] => )`, with whether `http://localhost/application/en` or `http://localhost/application/en/`
What should I do, please?

Comment: Thank you @Sahil, for the edit.

Comment: Just `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` and parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP. It performs better and is so much easier and more extensible.

Comment: Thank you @Niels, I do understand, but I just want a more structured and direct-to-the-point query sting, to make it work just the way I want it. If I wasn't working with multilingual system, I would remove the first part of the RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]*) and the rest would work just perfectly.

Comment: I'm just sharing the universal consensus that this is a Bad Idea. It's a free world.